# Add view from XML

Tags: android, view

I am creating one view from XML, I have defined one row in xml and in my main layout I am adding it through layout inflator and setting the id's of component( TextView, EditText, Button) run time. I have three requirements

1. User can add new row( It is done)
2. User can delete row ( It is done
3. I need to fetch the data from the created row. ( It is done too)

I am following this tutorial 
https://github.com/laoyang/android-dynamic-views#readme and it is great tutorial as well.

I am creating the ID of each component at run time and adding it to arraylist so that I can fetch the data from it through loop. i.e

for (EditText editText : Quanitity) {  }

1. Problem is that when user presses the delete button on each row, It deletes the row from the layout and its components as well through this code:

Main.removeView((View) v.getParent());

but its corresponding components ID's are already added to the arraylist. I want when user presses the delete button of the row I should get the position of it so that I can remove it through the arraylist as well.

1. Each row has a textview which is spinner style. I want to open the spinner on click of textview and value should be set for that Textview not all rows.

Please help me in this case. I am really stucked and deadline is today.

Thanks
aray

Answer (score 0):

First thing to achieve this is to get your selected view's ID and after that search the arraylist  for that id and if found delete it.That should look something similar to this :

```
int myEditTextID = myEditText.getId(); // ids of your selected editext
ids.remove(ids.indexOf(myEditTextID)); // ArrayList<Integer> where you are storing your ids.
```

The code above first get the id of your selected edittext and than search for the it's index in your arraylist and remove it.

That's all! : )

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the child in the `ViewGroup` with `indexOfChild(View)`. You may need to subtract an offset from that index depending on how many child views come before the rows you are adding (if any).

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild(android.view.View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild%28android.view.View%29)

```
public void onDeleteClicked(View v) {
    // get index
    int index = mContainerView.indexOfChild((View) v.getParent()) - offset;
    // remove from ArrayList
    myArrayList.remove(index);
    // remove the row by calling the getParent on button
    mContainerView.removeView((View) v.getParent());
}
```

You can get the offset by storing the initial index of the `ViewGroup` that you will be adding the views (rows) at before you add any. Which, in the case of the link provided (although unnecessary since it equals 0), would be something like this:

```
private int offset = 0; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // this should be equal to the index where the first row will be inserted
    // offset = 0 with the code in your link
    offset = mContainerView.getChildCount() - 1;

    // Add some examples
    inflateEditRow("Xiaochao");
    inflateEditRow("Yang");
}
```